# How-To limit user-names in LightDM login-screen when AccountsService is used

Tags: login-screen, lightdm

I have several "user" names in *passwd* that don't represent real people, and that should not appear on the LightDM login-screen. 
The *lightdm-gtk-greeter* configuration file clearly says that if AccountsService is installed, the program uses that and ignores its owh configureation files.
HOWEVER, there is less than nothing for documentation about how to configure AccountsService! 
Please, can someone tell me how to configure the system so that only an explicitly specified group of users are shown on the greeter?
I could uninstall AccountsService.  I did that before, but it comes back (dependencies, I suppose).

TIA

Comment: > actually, the UID needs to be < 500 […]
> before the greeter will exclude it from the list. Not on my system (Kubuntu 12.04). /etc/login.defs has the following line: UID_MIN 1000 … which takes precendent over what’s set in /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf tl;dr Change the value of “UID_MIN” in /etc/login.defs to suit your needs.

Comment: Less than nothing for documentation—agreed. The only _clue_ was a line in the man page for lightdm noting that `/etc/lightdm/users.conf` was only in effect "if not using Accounts Service."

Answer (score 2):

The simplest solution would be to change the UID of the non-user accounts to something below 1000. (Just tested, works)

... actually, the UID needs to be < 500 - and therefore nominally considered to be a 'system' UID - before the greeter will exclude it from the list. (the test referred above must have used such a value) 
HTH

Comment: See also [this Ask Ubuntu answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/139412/enabling-a-user-created-with-adduser-command-for-lightdm-graphical-login/145435#145435), which notes that the criterion for a UID to be considered a "system account" and hidden from the greeter is set in `/etc/login.defs`.

Answer (score 0):

As noted in [this elementaryOS thread](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/24669/how-can-i-hide-a-user-from-the-welcome-screen), you can create `/var/lib/AccountsService/users/THE_USER_NAME` with the following contents

```
[User]
SystemAccount=true
```

as root, then reboot the system, or log out and restart the following two services:

```
sudo systemctl restart accounts-daemon
sudo systemctl restart lightdm
```