# enabling a user (created with adduser command) for lightdm graphical login

Tags: lightdm, users

I just installed Ubuntu 12.04 AMD64 on a new (empty) hard disk (because the previous crashed)

Since I am quite familiar with Debian, I created two accounts with the `adduser` command.

Since I am also having an NFSv3 file system, I explictly gave user ids when creating them (for simplicity, I keep the same user id on the home server, running Debian; the user names contain digits; I'm not using LDAP), e.g.

```
  # grep bethy /etc/passwd
  bethy46:x:501:501:Bethy XXX,,,06123456:/home/bethy:/bin/bash
  # grep bethy /etc/group
  bethy64:x:501:
  # grep bethy /etc/shadow
  bethy46:$6$vQ-wmuchmorethings-2o/:15479:0:99999:7::
```

Of course `/home/bethy` exists

<sup>The actual user name is slightly different, and I am not showing the real entries (for obvious privacy reasons)</sup>

However, these users don't appear at graphical login prompt (lightdm).

And they exist in the system, they have entries in /etc/passwd & /etc/shadow and I (partly) restored their /home

I've got no specific user config under `/etc/lightdm` ; file `/etc/lightdm/users.conf` mentions

```
 # NOTE: If you have AccountsService installed on your system, then LightDM
 # will use this instead and these settings will be ignored
```

but I have no idea of how to deal with `AccountsService` thru the command line

<sup>As you probably guessed, I really dislike doing administrative tasks thru a graphical interface; I much prefer the command line</sup>

What did I do wrong? How can a user entry not appear in lightdm graphical login?   (I need to have my wife's user entry apparent for graphical login).

<sup>I am not asking how to hide a user, but how to *show* it in `lightdm` graphical prompt</sup>

#### work-around

As I have been told in comments by Nirmik and by Enzotib, `lightdm` probably don't show any users of uid less than 1024. So I changed all the uid to be more than 8200 (including on the Debian NFS server) and this made all the users visible at the graphical prompt.

It is a pain that such a threshold is not really documented.

Comment: In my `/etc/lightdm/users.conf` I have the line `minimum-uid=500`, that seems compatible with your user id.

Comment: @Rinzwind: I tested what the OP says, with `adduser --uid 501 some-name`, and the user in not shown in `lightdm`. I think `lightdm` follows `AccountService` prescriptions that are probably set to 1000, but I don't know how to solve. I think the question should not be closed.

Comment: I dont remember exactly where i have read it but lightdm does not display a user if the uid is below 1000.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch Less than `1024`? Most Ubuntu systems *only* have UID's lower than 1024. This would be breaking almost everyone's Ubuntu system, if that were the case. Do you mean `1000`, as Nirmik suggested?

Answer (score 5):

If there is `AccountService` running, the file `/etc/lightdm/users.conf` is ignored. In such case, you can set minimal UID by changing value of attribute `UID_MIN` in file `/etc/login.defs`.

Comment: This is the correct answer. What happens is that that AccountService thingy is a kind of wrapper for useradd, usermod and userdel so it reads the information from login.defs which is the file that stores configuration for the useradd command and for logins.

Answer (score 1):

I had exactly the same problem. My work around was to disallow lightdm to display valid usernames but rather to ask the user to type in her username. I didn't like that usernames were displayed anyway.

Happy i was until i noticed that SSHd also suffers from the same problem. I am logged in as xyz and yet when i try to ssh into my PC as xyz, i get a "Permission denied, please try again." And when i check the file /var/log/auth.log i find the following:

```
Jun  1 01:18:27 mypc sshd[17357]: input_userauth_request: invalid user xyz [preauth]

Jun  1 01:18:32 mypc sshd[17357]: error: Could not get shadow information for NOUSER

Jun  1 01:18:32 mypc sshd[17357]: Failed password for invalid user xyz from 123.123.123.123 port 57492 ssh2

Jun  1 01:18:36 mypc sshd[17357]: Failed password for invalid user xyz from 123.123.123.123 port 57492 ssh2

Jun  1 01:18:38 mypc sshd[17357]: Connection closed by 123.123.123.123 [preauth]
```

And yet connecting by SSH using the account with which i installed Ubuntu 12.04 works just fine.

The GUI to add new users is over-simplistic. I don't want to have to chown and chgrp all my data. What is the GUI doing that i've left out when editing passwd, group, shadow.

Answer (score 1):

Generally the uid 100~999 are reserved for system accounts and those should not
be used as normal user's uid, as described by `useradd` manual

> Values between 0 and 999 are typically reserved for system accounts.

Hence, using uid below `1000` causes lightdm not to show them. Try changing the uid value of the user above 999. (actually above 1000 because, the first user's uid which is you is 1000) For example, to set the uid `1004` use this command:

```
sudo usermod --uid 1004 bethy46
```

This will change the uid of user bethy46 to 1004 and thus showing in the lightdm user prompt.

To know the uid of a user named `user` use this command:

```
id -u user
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question but comes up when you search for a way to enable users to show up in Debian.  The way I've found to do this in Debian is to create a file in /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d called:

> ```
> 01_my.conf
> ```

Use root privileges.  I use nano but you can do this with gedit or a similar text editor.

> ```
> mkdir /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d
> nano /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d/01_my.conf
> ```

Add the following:

> ```
> [Seat:*]
> greeter-hide-users=false
> ```

Save your changes, exit and reboot or logout.  Now your computer should show your user.

I found this [here.](https://wiki.debian.org/LightDM)